# Launching Instance from AMI Creates two disk devices when only one is expected

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, amazon-ami

First some background.  I am migrating an Ubuntu Instance-store backed ec2 instance to EBS using the steps outlined in [Create an AMI from an instance store-backed instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/create-instance-store-ami.html).

Everything works correctly and I am able to create and register my AMI using:

```
aws ec2 register-image --region us-east-1 --name MASTER_EBS_AMI --block-device-mappings DeviceName=/dev/xvda,Ebs={SnapshotId=snap-0dd...} --virtualization-type hvm --architecture x86_64 --root-device-name /dev/xvda
```

I can successfully launch the new instance but when I look at the block devices I am expecting to see just /dev/xvda but there is also /dev/sda.  /dev/xvda is a volume as expected but there is no trace of any volume for /dev/sda which isn't ideal since it does not allow snapshots (as far as I can tell).

At first I though perhaps they were the same device (identical contents) but after creating a unique file in each it was clear that they are indeed different.

My best guess is that the launch process is somehow copying the snapshot into both /dev/xvda and /dev/sda and booting from /dev/sda.  /dev/sda seems ephemeral but the storage details say it is EBS and data is indeed persisted across a system stop / re-start;

[image: Storage Settings]

I've tried everything I can to find an explanation of what is happening here but everything I read suggests that it should behave exactly as I expect (i.e. one volume is created an mounted and is called /dev/sda or /dev/xvda).

Having the extra device isn't a big deal but I need to understand how exactly to access the underlying EBS or switch it to have just the one device.

Comment: So, not that anyone appears to be reading this (I suspect I'm about 5 years too late for this post), I did some more tests and discovered that these two disks are definitely the same but the contents written to /dev/sda aren't flushed to the EBS until it is shut down.  There is definitely something funky going on with the drivers or possibly elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'm facing the same issue, in my case I noticed when we try to create an ami from a specific Bitnami instance, some ephemeral volumes appear, even if these volumes didn't exist for the instance.